# What wrong with run-jetty in the Clojure webapps with Ring?

Tags: clojure, webserver, ring

Writing a tiny web app in clojure, when I execute the program in REPL, encountered an error in calva-repl (**; No such var: jetty/run-jetty**), Please comment what wrong with the program, thank you

### Error

**; No such var: jetty/run-jetty**

### deps.edn in :deps section

```
;;
ring/ring-core {:mvn/version "1.10.0"}
ring/ring-jetty-adapter {:mvn/version "1.10.0"}}
```

### Source code

```
(ns ring-app.ring-app
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]))

(defn app [req]
  {:body "hello world!"})

(jetty/run-jetty app {:port 3000})
```

Comment: Since you saw it in a REPL - did you evaluate the `(ns ...)` form before evaluating the `(jetty/run-jetty ...)` form?

Comment: @akond thank for your reply. typo in this post, it is :deps

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, thank for your reply. I did line by line in calve-repl.

Comment: This code runs just fine here (not using calva, just the clj REPL). The
most plausible explanation is that you have not evaluated the require --
or there where an error with the require, you missed.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for your help. disables some libraries in deps.edn, it works. It seems there are incompatible in-between different libraries. thanks you